# How to catch node TimeoutError and log the request?

Tags: node.js, websocket, timeout, try-catch

I'm writing an application in node in which I do many websocket requests to a remote service (using the [ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws)). So the remote service is the server, and my node application is the client. It works quite well, but occasionally I suddenly get a long list of the following TimeoutError:

```
Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out
    at ResourceRequest._fireTimeout (/Users/kramer65/repos/mmj/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:58:17)
    at Timeout.bound (/Users/kramer65/repos/mmj/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:8:15)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

Since I do many different websocket calls I now wonder for which call this error occurs. I tried wrapping the `ws.send()` in a try/catch as I pasted below, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
try {
    ws.send(request_json);
} catch(e) {
    console.log('WEBSOCKET ERROR', e);
    console.log('WEBSOCKET JSON', request_json);
}
```

Does anybody know how I can catch the TimeoutError and log the request contents? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
As suggested by @Mark_M I added a callback to the ws.send() method as follows:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(request_obj)), (error)=>{
    console.log('WEBSOCKET ERROR', request_obj.action, error);
});
```

Unfortunately I still get the same errors as I posted on the top of this question.

[EDIT2]
I also tried the suggestion made by @wrangler:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(request_obj));
ws.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log('WEBSOCKET ONERROR', request_obj.action, event);
};
ws.onclose = function (event){
    console.log('WEBSOCKET ONCLOSE', request_obj.action, event);
};
```

but unfortunately this also doesn't seem to work. I still get the same errors as I posted on the top of this question.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The ws.library `send()` method takes an optional callback that will be called when it encounters an error. You can catch those errors with:

```
ws.send('something', function ack(error) {
   if(error) //handle error
}
```

Try/catch will catch immediate errors, but, as you noticed, it doesn't help with async errors.

Alternatively, it looks like you are calling `send()` within some other async code (because you aren't just getting an error, you're getting an unhandled promise rejection). You could add a `.catch()` onto that promise if it's in your own code.

Comment: I tried your code, but once I did, I still got the same errors as before. So they are not caught by the ack error callback. I added it to my initial question. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onerror` callback of websocket object for receiving any error.

Example:

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
    exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log("open");
      exampleSocket.send("hellow world"); 
    };
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    }

    exampleSocket.onerror=function(event){
        console.log("Error");
    }
```

Link:http://jsfiddle.net/g28yuymv/1/

Link2:http://jsfiddle.net/g28yuymv/10/

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I still get the `Unhandled rejection TimeoutError` I got initially. Any idea what else I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, stupid me. After looking at the initial error a bit better I found that it was an error in the `generic-pool` package. On [its npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generic-pool) it says it's

> a Promise based API, which can be used to reuse or throttle usage of
>   expensive resources such as database connections

The problem turned out to be my database connection (which is used extensively). I solved it using [this tip on github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7884#issuecomment-313853545), which suggests to set the sequelize init pool settings as follows:

pool: {max: 5, min: 0, idle: 20000, acquire: 20000}

That solved it for me.

Thanks to the answers, I now have proper websocket error reporting though.. :-)